# Scroll backward circular array

Tags: java, circular-buffer

I have an array and I want to scroll the positions in it backward.

I have a boolean array and I need to count how many true are there from a given cell going forward and backward.

I know that if N is the number of elements into the array, I can go ahead doing i=(i+1)%N.
But what if I need to scroll it in the opposite way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Minus 1 instead of plus 1...

Comment: If i=0, (i-1)%N results -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This should do it:**

```
i--;
if (i == -1)
  i = N-1;
```

**Or in 1 line:**

```
i = ((i-1 == -1) ? N-1 : i-1);
```

But noise's variation of the above is probably better. **A related if-statement version:**

```
if (i == 0)
  i = N-1;
else
  i--;
```

**A related 1-line version:**

```
i = (i == 0 ? N-1 : i-1)
```

Answer (score 11):

I usually use `i = (i - 1 + N) % N` to prevent negative values.

Answer (score 5):

```
int newRightShiftIndex = (curIndex + numOfPositions)%size;
int newLeftShiftIndex = (curIndex +(size-(numOfPositions%size)))%size;
```

- **curIndex** - is your curent index
- **numOfPositions** - number of positions you want to shift backwards or clockwise
- **size** - length, size of array

Answer (score 1):

How about `i = (i == 0 ? N : i) - 1`?